# Laptop numpad very hot to touch

Tags: keyboard, overheating

I feel the numpad section of my laptop's keyboard hot when I type my PIN. The standard keyboard section is normal. Fan is loud. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your laptop likely has the HDD or CPU/GPU situated under the numpad - if it's a mechanical HDD, there's little you can do outside of replacing it with an SSD, as mechanical HDDs create significant amounts of heat, whereas SSDs only do so when under heavy load for extended periods. If it's the CPU/GPU, @John's answer would be recommended and you may want to elevate the bottom of the laptop via stand/lap pad to allow for better air circulation, also ensuring there are no objects in close proximity to the laptop's vents.

Comment: @JW0914 I have a SSD laptop.

Answer (score 2):

If the keyboard is hot and the fan is running fast, then almost for sure, there is an accumulation of dust inside the laptop.

You need to shut it down, remove the battery, open the case and clean it out inside. Soft brush and very light vacuum to pick up the dust.

Get it clean, close it up and test.

Comment: The part of the keyboard for typing text and the F keys are normal temp.

Comment: I would clean anyway as described. The num pad could be over a heat producing part. Best to be clean.

Comment: @John is correct, if you can't open the laptop, simply try to blow compressed air in the all vents on the PC. The processor is usually the hot part & is in a different location on different laptops, so the location of the hotness doesn't really matter

Comment: @gregg Compressed air from a can, sure, compressed air from a tank, no, as normal tank CFMs will destroy the fan's motor.